# How to find out the maximum used stack space?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, memory

I am creating an Arduino sketch which involves quite some classes, and I want to check if it will run on an Arduino Uno or Mega (2 KB vs 8 KB SRAM).

So far my global variables take up around 1,200 bytes, and I expect this will rise. However, beyond that I need to make sure the stack memory is not using up too much. **How can I find the maximum used stack size?**.

I can check manually by calculating the maximum function stack and calculating all parameters + local variables, but this is a very tedious job (especially since my application changes still a lot).

Or another way: I know it is possible to get the free space, but should I add this in 'strategic' locations or in the beginning of all functions and continue from there? (there will be many of them).

Or is there preferable some static way of checking this?

The application works within Visual Studio C++ as stand alone too, so maybe that helps for some solution.

I expect the stack size easily to be a few hundred bytes (which is quite a lot for the Arduino Uno SRAM).

Comment: Could always use Atmega1284P as well with 16K SRAM space.  I had a project with 45 shift registers, 325 rows of data, that were updated and blasted out over SPI at 20 KHz rate, used 14,625 bytes of SRAM.

Comment: @CrossRoads: Can I find a (cheap) Arduino compatible-board with an AtMega1284P? . Actually, as alternative I can use a Mega, and for my 'main' project where I need more memory, I am intending to use an STM32 later.

Comment: Look here, www.crossroadsfencing.com/BobuinoRev17  Add 1284 core files to the Arduino IDE  https://github.com/MCUdude/MCUdude_corefiles

Comment: You should clarify: are talking about the heap (as in the title) or the stack (as in the question body)?

Comment: @CrossRoads cool to be able to use that, but I saw beyond the not so cheap price I rather use a Mega, and another CPU to do the real work. But good to know there are AtMega CPUs capable of more (I didn't knew that.)

Comment: @EdgarBonet Yes, mistake from my side, I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: You'd maybe want to use stack painting or ask GCC about the stack usage by adding `-fstack-usage`, for both see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390246/5296568. There are also post-analysis tools like https://github.com/PeterMcKinnis/WorstCaseStack. Also see https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/arduino-stack-painting/

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks for this info; maybe I can use it on the Windows version to get a good idea already beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Knowing the stack size is pretty easy: the stack pointer is initially
set to `RAMEND` and goes down as the stack grows. Thus:

```c++
static inline size_t stack_size()
{
    return RAMEND - SP;
}
```

> should I add this in 'strategic' locations [...]

Obviously, the result will depend on where this is evaluated. Ideally
you should test this in the deepest parts of your call chain, as this is
where the stack will be at its maximum size. Note that ISRs stack on top
of all your regular code.

**Edit**: There is no easy way to know the *maximum* stack size. You
could get an approximation by sampling the stack at regular intervals,
e.g.:

```
#include <util/atomic.h>

volatile size_t min_sp = RAMEND;

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    if (SP < min_sp)
        min_sp = SP;
}

static inline size_t max_stack_size()
{
    size_t min_sp_copy;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_FORCEON) {
        min_sp_copy = min_sp;
    }
    return RAMEND - min_sp_copy;
}
```

If you enable `TIMER0_COMPA` interrupt in `setup()`:

```
TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
```

then the stack size will be sampled every 1.024 ms. Note, however,
that this ISR is itself using some stack space for its own purposes
(9 bytes in my experiment), and that this is not sampling other
ISRs or critical sections.

Comment: Thanks, the interrupt way is indeed great to check the maximum size. And good to know about the RAMEND / SP variables (registers).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: `RAMEND` is actually a constant defined in <avr/io.h>. `SP` is indeed an IO register or, rather, a pair of registers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This assumes you do not use the heap: no new, no malloc, no String objects. A good idea on small controllers, anyway.

Comment: @DataFiddler: The question title was about heap (has been fixed since), but the question body is about stack. My answer specifically addresses the stack, not the heap.

Comment: I do not zing you for your response, @Edgar. SP is very easy to use. Much nicer than `(int)&aTempLocalVariable`. My comment were just my two cents on "stack size is irrelevant if you do not know your dynamic heap requirements".

Answer (score 7):

Initialize the entire SRAM space from the top of the heap to the bottom of the stack, either during setup, or in a modified version of the Arduino-provided main() function, with some unlikely pattern, such as {0x55, 0xAA, ...} or "UnusedUnused...".

After your program has run a while, examine memory for dirty footprints, reading up from the top of heap to find the highest heap excursion, and down from the stack-pointer to find the lowest address used by stack. You could use a debugger if you have one, or just a hex & ASCII dump to the terminal. Pick through it with whatever tools you have handy on your PC. If there's been no collision and you're using a memory dump, it's pretty easy to start somewhere in the middle that wasn't disturbed, and scroll in either direction. The place where your initialized pattern has been overwritten usually stands out very plainly.

Comment: I upvoted it because it's another idea, but I think just printing the value seems easier.... or is it possible to download a 'hex dump' from a running program? (e.g. by the Arduino IDE)

Comment: I send the hex dump to the Arduino terminal, save it to a PC file, and inspect it on the PC.

Comment: Thanks also sounds like an interesting idea. Thanks